# Знак препинания при приложении

Tags: пунктуация

******* *****И увидели аквариум()большой стеклянный необычный дом морской рыбы, дно которого было обложено разноцветными камешками.************

Учитель белорусского языка говорит, что на месте пропуска нужно ставить именно тире. 
Однако я не понимаю, почему именно так. Понятия, в принципе, равноправные, никакого уточнения, как мне кажется, здесь нет. Растолкуйте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Учитель белорусского языка - грамотный человек и знает, что приложение, носящее пояснительный характер, отделяется не запятой, а тире, особенно если стоит в конце предложения. В Вашем примере придаточное предложение "...дно которого было обложено..." прибавлено к приложению, поэтому его можно рассматривать как часть приложения. Таким образом, Ваше предложение должно выглядеть так:
"И увидели аквариум - большой стеклянный необычный дом морской рыбы, дно которого было обложено разноцветными камешками". Таким образом, все приложение обозначает (поясняет), что собой представляет аквариум. Кстати, здесь вполне уместно иметь  в виду слово "а именно"

Comment: Осталось спросить учителя японского.

Comment: ?????????????????????????

Answer (score 0):

А учитель хорошо понимает, что это написано на русском?
Вообще-то вполне можно трактовать именно как уточнение.

Comment: Учитель прекрасно разговаривает на русском.
Вот в предложении:"Официант поставил на стол холодные,  горячие закуски, а также главное блюдо – фаршированную семгу", со знаками вопросов не возникает, так как здесь действительно можно вставить " а именно?". А вот в примере, предложенном выше, эта замена как раз невозможна. Я не понимаю,но мне кажется, что понятия обозначают как раз таки одно и то же. Аквариум = стеклянный дом морской рыбы.

Comment: >Учитель прекрасно разговаривает на русском.  
Надеюсь. Но зачем тогда упоминать о том, что он - учитель белорусского?  

>Аквариум = стеклянный дом морской рыбы.  
И почему это исключает встевку "а именно"?

В любом сдучае тут вполне применимо и другое правило:
§ 168. Тире ставится перед приложением, стоящим в конце предложения: 
...
2. Если при приложении есть пояснительные слова и необходимо подчеркнуть оттенок самостоятельности такого приложения, например: 
  
Со мною был чугунный чайник – единственная отрада моя в путешествиях по Кавказу.   
Лермонтов  
(Правила-56)

Answer (score 0):

И увидели аквариум - большой стеклянный необычный дом морской рыбы, - дно которого было обложено разноцветными камешками.

"Которого" относится к аквариуму, а не к "дому". большой стеклянный необычный дом морской рыбы - вставная конструкция, а не приложение.

И увидели банку - большой стеклянный необычный дом морской рыбы, - дно которой [не которого] было обложено разноцветными камешками.